# Can we directly apply for EU Blue card, or do I need a work visa for Germany? [Software professional] [India] [Have Job offer]

Tags: visa, working-visas, germany, blue-card

I currently have a job offer by a German company for an indefinite period contract and the salary offered is above the standard as suggested for having a EU Blue card as well as I have verified the requirements (university, skilled workers etc.) and they do match to my qualifications.

I need to understand whether, I can directly apply for EU Blue Card or do I have to have a work visa and apply for the EU Blue card after reaching Germany? There are lot of forums wherein these details are in contrast to each other.

I am from India, and I have also tried to get in touch with the German consulate, but the phone is continuously unavailable.

Comment: @simbabque - thank you so much for provided information. I am actually eligible for applying for EU blue card visa. And was hoping to apply for the same. Just wanted to clarify if you meant that applying for normal work visa is better than applying for EU blue card visa?
Also - do you know if EU blue card processing time in germany is better or worse than applying normal work permit. Thank you for your time. I am from India, if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to figure this out after a couple of emails to the German consulate. 
The answer is:

No, we can't apply for a Blue card directly; but once we have a German national visa, and we travel to Germany, only then can we apply for a blue card.

Comment: That should not be the necessary. You should be able to apply for a _Blaue Karte EU_ directly at the embassy or consulate. They will do all the initial checking, verification of your degree and so on. They will then issue you a temporary work visa and possibly a _Familiennachzugsvisum_ for your spouse and children. With those, you can enter Germany. There, you have to go to _Auslaenderbehoerde_ in your city, and tell them you are there. That will start the process of Bundesdruckerei producing the actual §19a visa for you. In the meantime, you're allowed to work, but your spouse isn't...

Comment: ... until you get the physical _Aufenthaltstitel_ that says it's for §19a Blaue Karte EU. With the temporary one, you can typically also not travel freely in the Schengen zone. It is possible to do all of this in Germany and come in with a different visa, which might be faster if the verification process in your country takes longer, though.

Comment: @simbabque perhaps you should post that information as an answer.  The temporary work visa will allow free travel in the Schengen area, however, as do all national (type D) visas.

Comment: @phoog I don't have sources besides being of assistance to people doing that from the German end. And as far as I know, it can be different from case to case.

Comment: @simbabque What's this temporary work visa? A Schengen short-stay visa? Otherwise, I don't see what's not necessary, the procedure you describe sounds very similar to the one described in the answer.

Comment: @Gala I don't know. The people I helped who needed a visa to enter Germany never went through with it unfortunately. The procedure sounds the same because it is the same. I meant to add more information.

Answer (score -1):

Blue card application is no different than work visa. They are essentially the same thing.

One can apply only for Work Visa. Once you do, if you meet also requirements of blue card (gross salary, university degrees etc), you will be given one. Otherwise it is work visa.