# Immigrating to Germany from India

Tags: working-visas, germany, indian-citizens, blue-card, paperwork

I am an Indian national and a Software Engineer. I have received a job offer in Germany and they agreed to support me in acquiring the Blue Card.
I have never been to Germany before and thus have no idea how things work there.

So, my question is, what sort of documents do I need for the blue card and how much time it'll take?

Another question is I am going there for another job interview and will apply for a travel visa next week. Will that create any problem with my blue card application?

Comment: See https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12619/can-we-directly-apply-for-eu-blue-card-or-do-i-need-a-work-visa-for-germany-s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we directly apply for EU Blue card, or do I need a work visa for Germany? \[Software professional\] \[India\] \[Have Job offer\]](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/12619/can-we-directly-apply-for-eu-blue-card-or-do-i-need-a-work-visa-for-germany-s)

Comment: If you have an answer, by now. Could you post it?